# Streaming serialized on demand data

Tags: c#, .net-core, serialization

I have a thirdparty client, that takes a Stream and sends it to some server as StreamContent.
I need to send a large amount of data there.
Current approach is to serialize all the data to MemoryStream and pass it to the third party client.

As I understand, when the time comes to write data to socket a buffer is created and data is read from the stream to this buffer and then written to socket (rinse repeat).

I want to try another approach: write a custom stream implementation, that will have all the data to send and serialize the data items one by one on demand - when the Read method is called.

And I cannot stop thinking, that somebody has already made a custom Stream implementation for this, but I cannot find it.

To demonstrate the approach, some pseudocode:

```
public class MyStream : Stream
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<object> _data;

    private readonly byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024]; // somehow calculated max size for a data record

    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override bool CanSeek => false;

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override long Length => -1;

    public override long Position { get => throw new InvalidOperationException(); set => throw new InvalidOperationException(); }

    public MyStream(IEnumerable<object> data)
    {
        _data = data ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        // serialize next one entity to _buffer
        // copy from _buffer to buffer
        // if buffer not full, repeat

        return ...;
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Can you share your thought about this approach and, if it is possible, useful nuget packages for it?